# Problem with Eclipse/Jetty in Tapestry 5 Tutorial

Tags: eclipse, tapestry

I'm working through [this Tapestry 5 tutorial](http://tapestry.apache.org/loading-the-project-into-eclipse.html) and I'm stuck on the "Running the Application inside Eclipse" step.

When I go to the Eclipse run configurations, select Jetty Webapp, then click New, I get the following error:

> An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
>   Path for project must have only one segment.

Any suggestions on this one? I'm not new to web development, but I am new to Eclipse and Tapestry.

Comment: The message is cryptic, but: Did you set your project as the project to run in the dialog?

Comment: No. The error was immediate -- as soon as I clicked the New button -- and wouldn't resolve even when I typed in the values. The Run button was greyed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure why, but after I ran Project > Clean... I could then add the run configuration just fine.